# Create REST API using Django

Tags: django

I have a python script to test REST APIs for CRUD operations. The APIs have been built in JAVA and to test them, input data to be posted is created in JSON/XML/YAML files and then we append the file path in the URL itself and hit the same, which returns the response back in the respective format. Now I need to create same APIs using django, for which i have been having a hard time. All i could find on google is posting data using form but nowhere from a json file. But suppose I do not want a form, I just want a URL to take input from flat file and update the database. Is it possible to create such API using django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django REST framework is a powerful and flexible toolkit for building Web APIs.

**Some reasons you might want to use REST framework:**

1.The Web browsable API is a huge usability win for your developers.

2.Serialization that supports both ORM and non-ORM data sources.

you can use [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

git link [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Django rest framework is best option for you if you are using Django framework.

**There are several powerful features that gives back for your development**

- Class based views
- Simple CRUD operations can be dealt easily with DRF (formally Django rest framework )
- Yet having power of class based API views, you can also use low level APIs.
- It consists of various authentication methods. i.e OAuth1, OAuth2
- Serializer feature supports both Django ORM and non ORM source of data.
- Used and trusted by software geek companies including **Mozilla, Red Hat, Heroku,** and **Eventbrite**.
- refer https://www.django-rest-framework.org/ for more